# JPA Entity Mappings between two tables

Tags: jpa, entity

I keep getting the following error with my Entity mappings.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: edu.indstate.ics.transcript.web.dao.entity.Swrhxml.swbhxml in edu.indstate.ics.transcript.web.dao.entity.Swbhxml.swrhxmls
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Could use some insight and help on what I am missing here.

My Entity classes are as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SWBHXML" )
public class Swbhxml implements DatabaseObject, Serializable {
    private List<Swrhxml> swrhxmls;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long swbhxmlTransId; 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "SWBHXML_TRANS_ID", nullable = false)
    public Long getSwbhxmlTransId() {
        return swbhxmlTransId;
    }

    public void setSwbhxmlTransId(Long swbhxmlTransId) {
        this.swbhxmlTransId = swbhxmlTransId;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "swbhxml", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Swrhxml> getSwrhxmls() {
        return swrhxmls;
    }

    public void setSwrhxmls(List<Swrhxml> swrhxmls) {
        this.swrhxmls = swrhxmls;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SWRHXML" )
public class Swrhxml implements DatabaseObject, Serializable {

    private Swbhxml swbhxml;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long SwrhxmlTransId;
    private String SwrhxmlHxpsCode;
    private Date SwrhxmlTimeStamp; 

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
    @JoinColumn(name="SWBHXML_TRANS_ID")
    public Swbhxml getSwrhxml() {
        return swbhxml;
    }

    public void setSwrhxml(Swbhxml swbhxml) {
        this.swbhxml = swbhxml;
    }

    @Column(name = "SWRHXML_HXPS_CODE", length = 15)
    public String getSwrhxmlHxpsCode() {
        return SwrhxmlHxpsCode;
    }

    public void setSwrhxmlHxpsCode(String SwrhxmlHxpsCode) {
        this.SwrhxmlHxpsCode = SwrhxmlHxpsCode;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "SWRHXML_TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getSwrhxmlTimeStamp() {
        return SwrhxmlTimeStamp;
    }

    public void setSwrhxmlTimeStamp(Date SwrhxmlTimeStamp) {
        this.SwrhxmlTimeStamp = SwrhxmlTimeStamp;
    }
}
```

Comment: The message says that the mappedBy attribute is "mytable", and not "myTable" as it should be. So either you're not showing us the right code, or you're not showing us the right error message, or you forgot to compile/deploy the new code.

Comment: you are correct... I edited the error msg to better reflect. The Table names were changed for this posting and corrected the error message.

Comment: Don't do that. Post the REAL error message, and the REAL code.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I updated the code.  I appreciate your feedback.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use

```
`mappedBy = "swbhxml"`
               ^
               |___ b here
```

, but the annotated association is

```
Swbhxml getSwrhxml()
             ^
             |___ r here
```

Your getter and setter are named incorrectly. And frankly, with such cryptic and close entity names, you'll probably have many such bugs.